# Null Pointer Exception occuring during graph generation

Tags: android, graph, nullpointerexception

Friends.. I am trying to drawing some graph. My application is running fine for first attempt but when I am trying to draw the graph repeatedly for 2,3 attempts then it is showing Null Pointer exception...What will be the solution? Here is my code:

```
public class ECG extends Activity { 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context cnt;
    Callback c; 
    Camera mCamera; 
    boolean mFinished;  
    DrawMyGraph g;
    ImageView clock,graph_Text,heart_Index,graph_View;
    static long startTime = 0;
    static int beats = 0;
    volatile boolean show=false;
    SurfaceHolder sh;
    SurfaceView sv;
    TextView show_BPM;
    Button on,off;
    int no,count=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    show_BPM=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showBPM);
    sv=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    clock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.clock);
    graph_Text=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.graphText);
    heart_Index=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.heartIndex);
    graph_View=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.graphview);
    graph_Text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graphtext2);
    on=(Button)findViewById(R.id.on);
    off=(Button)findViewById(R.id.off);

    Random r=new Random();
     no=r.nextInt(84-60)+60;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "cover the camera with your index finger......!";
    int duration = 100000;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    ///////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////



    g = new DrawMyGraph(this, 26);
    addContentView(g, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    startCamPreview();



}

public void startCamPreview() {
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    SurfaceHolder sh = sv.getHolder();
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sh);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sh.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Deleted");
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            System.out.println("Created");

            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

                    int width = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int height = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                    byte[] mYUVData = new byte[data.length];
                    int[] mRGBData = new int[width * height];
                    System.arraycopy(data, 0, mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                    decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, width, height);
                    int[] mRedHistogram = new int[256];
                    calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram,
                            width, height, 0);
                    double imageRedMean = 0;
                    double redHistogramSum = 0;
                    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++) {
                        imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                        redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                    } // bin
                    imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
                    double[] mBinSquared;
                    mBinSquared = new double[256];
                    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++) {
                        mBinSquared[bin] = ((double) bin) * bin;
                    }
                    double imageRed2ndMoment = 0;
                    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++) {
                        imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin]
                                * mBinSquared[bin];
                    } // bin
                    imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
                    double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt((imageRed2ndMoment
                            - imageRedMean * imageRedMean));
                    int val = (new Double(imageRedStdDev * 100000)
                            .intValue());

                    show_BPM.setText(String.valueOf(no));
                    int v = new Double(imageRedStdDev).intValue();

                    for (int l = 0; l < 1; l++) {

                    }
                    int yVal=250;
                    if (imageRedStdDev < 15 && val != 0)
                    {
                        show=true;
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        float flt=(float)Math.random();
                        g.addPoint(yVal+flt*25);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        flt=(float)Math.random();
                        g.addPoint(yVal-flt*20);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        flt=(float)Math.random();
                        g.addPoint(yVal-flt*30);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        flt=(float)Math.random();
                        g.addPoint(yVal+flt*35);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    } else {
                        show=false;
                        if(val==0){

                            count++;
                            g.addPoint(yVal);
                            g.addPoint(yVal);
                            g.addPoint(yVal);
                            g.addPoint(yVal);
                            show_BPM.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                        }else{

                        count++;
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        g.addPoint(yVal);
                        show_BPM.setText(String.valueOf(0));


                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            System.out.println("Changed");
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
            parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            g.invalidate();
        }
    });
    // fl.addView(b);
}

static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width,
        int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0)
                y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0)
                r = 0;
            else if (r > 262143)
                r = 262143;
            if (g < 0)
                g = 0;
            else if (g > 262143)
                g = 262143;
            if (b < 0)
                b = 0;
            else if (b > 262143)
                b = 262143;

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000)
                    | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
}

static public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram,
        int width, int height, int component) {
    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++) {
        histogram[bin] = 0;
    } // bin
    if (component == 0) // red
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width * height; pix += 3) {
            int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
            histogram[pixVal]++;
        } // pix
    } else if (component == 1) // green
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width * height; pix += 3) {
            int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
            histogram[pixVal]++;
        } // pix
    } else // blue
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width * height; pix += 3) {
            int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
            histogram[pixVal]++;
        } // pix


    }
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    clock.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clockanimation);
    AnimationDrawable clock_Anim=new AnimationDrawable();
    clock_Anim=(AnimationDrawable)clock.getBackground();
    clock_Anim.start();
    timer.start();
    }

CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(30000,1000){

    @Override
    public void onFinish()throws NullPointerException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCamera.stopPreview();**//This is the line for which shows NullPointer exception**
        g.invalidate();
        Canvas.freeGlCaches();
        graph_Text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graphtext3);
        if(count>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Hiiiiiii");
        show_BPM.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Helllooo");
            show_BPM.setText(String.valueOf(no));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

    class DrawMyGraph extends View {
    public LinkedList<Float> yValues = null;
    private int size = 0;
    private LinkedList<Integer> xValues = null;
    private LinkedList<Long> beatList = new LinkedList<Long>();

    public DrawMyGraph(Context context, int size) {
        super(context);
        yValues = new LinkedList<Float>();
        int inc = 5;
        this.size = size * inc;
        xValues = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        int cnt = 468;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size * inc; i++) {
            xValues.add(cnt);
            cnt = cnt - (inc - 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(2 , 2, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        graph_View.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        invalidate();
        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < yValues.size() && j < yValues.size(); i++, j++) {


            canvas.drawLine(xValues.get(i) + 30, (yValues.get(i) - 10)*2,
                    xValues.get(j) + 30, (yValues.get(j) - 10)*2, paint);




        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
}

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void addPoint(float p) {
        if (yValues.size() > size) {
            yValues.removeLast();
        }
        yValues.addFirst(p);
    }

    public void addBeat(long beat) {
        beatList.add(beat);
    }

}
     public void onBackPressed() {



            finish();
           return;
        }   

}
```

this is what my logcat saying

> 02-10 17:34:25.570: W/dalvikvm(3681): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40015578) 02-10 17:34:25.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-10 17:34:25.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3681): java.lang.NullPointerException 02-10
>   17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at
>   com.android.ecg.ECG$1.onFinish(ECG.java:312) 02-10 17:34:25.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3681):   at
>   android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
>   02-10 17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-10
>   17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 02-10 17:34:25.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3681):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 02-10
>   17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-10
>   17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 02-10 17:34:25.574:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3681):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   02-10 17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 02-10
>   17:34:25.574: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: please reformat your question.. Also paste your NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please post the null pointer exception aswell

Comment: I really wish people would use the preview section to check their code formatting...

Comment: And please sorry for bad code formatting,I am new to this,i will take care of all this later...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It is recommended to not post a complete activity as long as it is something "simple" as a NPE. The amount of code makes it hard to see the issue.

I guess that your timer access the mCamera object before your camera is ready. You should check if mCamera is null before calling a method on the object. Alternative make sure that the timer will not be started before the camera is ready.

Comment: Thank you, And i will take care of that code posting issue from next attempt